# ViewModels per View

Tags: wpf, mvvm

How many ViewModel should I have per WPF application? Does View stands for one xaml file or for "one display area"? Assuming that I am having left panel and document panel in MainWindow.xaml should I split it into LeftPanelViewModel and DocumentPanelViewModel ? Are left panel and document panel separated views?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest  you to have two ViewModels, LeftPanelViewModel and DocumentPanelViewModel, in order to maintain your code easily. Because your View can contains lot of lines of code ( binded Properties, command, function, etc...)

1 View => 1 ViewModel

Comment: so View isn't "rigidly sticked" to the .xaml file?

Comment: You can have two views => two files xaml, i suggest you also to install prism framework , he gives lot of functionalities ...

Comment: but these panels are part of custom control and I can't split it into 2 xaml. Can one view describe just part of one .xaml? I am using mvvm light.